# Why do generators run in parallel when batteries don't?

Tags: generator

The one generator sees the other as a resistance in parallel. How can they run even when they share an uneven active and/or reactive power? Why does most of the current does flow into the parallel generator? Don't batteries need protection to run in parallel?

Comment: Batteries run just fine in parallel.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes but with the necessary protection

Comment: The purpose of generators is to push current into a load. Why would a generator see another generator as resistance in parallel, if they are both just sharing the total load? And batteries are sometimes connected in parallel; even without protection, to make a single larger capacity battery, such as in boats and power banks.

Comment: For the argument, please add to your question whether to discuss DC, 3-phase or other types of generators.

Comment: Identical batteries run in parallel without protection.  It is how you get larger current.

Comment: They don't. Power plant operators have to be careful to keep their generators in sync with all the other generators. Once they are in sync, they are forced to stay in sync. You literally cannot stop a generator from spinning once it's connected to the grid.

Comment: @veronika Batteries don't need protection to run in parallel. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: @DKNguyen No they don't. In particular, fires have been started by clueless people connecting two Li-ion batteries in parallel at different states of charge,

Comment: @DavideAndrea I would call that improper use or assembly rather than batteries *needing* protection to run in parallel. Certainly, they are much less fussy about being run in parallel than generators when the OP stated they are more fussy.

Answer (score 4):

Synchronous generators in an AC grid can only run in parallel because the load distribution between them is actively controlled.

When the control system of a power station finds that the generator does not deliver the set target current to the grid, the current in the field winding is increased. That increases the mechanical load on the turbine and also increases the voltage and current at the generator output.

In addition, each power station monitors the frequency of the grid. If it increases, that means less load is on the grid. All power stations decrease their target current then.

And vice versa.

That way there's always current flow from the generators to the load, and not from one generator to the other. You don't have that with batteries as they cannot adjust their voltage as required.

Comment: An unregulated generator would still provide current into the grid as long as something (a steam turbine) was trying to make it spin harder than the grid does. Of course, actual generators do have regulation because they want to control how much current they are providing, e.g. to make as much money as possible.

Comment: It cannot spin faster as the frequency is set by the grid. A single generator has only a minimal influence on that. So "spin harder" can only mean more or less torque. If your field is fixed ("unregulated") the torque is only a function of the current, and that one is a function of the inner voltage of the generator vs the grid voltage. But as you have your field fixed and the speed is fixed as well, you cannot control the inner voltage. Whether you can deliver current to the grid or not completely depends on the voltage of the grid at your node, **which is terribly load-dependent.**

Comment: So you can't have that. You must regulate the field.

Comment: I did say "trying harder" and not "spinning faster". Doesn't the field strength affect both motor and generator operation?

Comment: "Trying harder" means more torque. As I wrote, the current determines the torque, and the difference between the inner voltage of the generator and the grid voltage determines the current. But the inner voltage of the generator depends on its speed and the field strength! Both are fixed by your requirement of "unregulated". That means if the grid has higher voltage than the internal voltage, the generator will not require torque from the turbine but rather than that, it provides torque! It's a motor then.The grid will turn the turbine and operate it as a fan.

Answer (score 3):

Batteries in parallel don't have to evenly share current, either, as long as the voltage is the same. When two things are in parallel, their voltage is forced to be the same - any would-be voltage difference will cause current to flow from one battery to the other to equalize it. Once the voltage is equalized, that means each battery is supplying current to the best of its ability. If you connect batteries with wildly different voltages the equalizing current can be very high and could even cause an explosion. If you make sure the voltages are equal (or almost equal) before connecting them, then it's fine.

I am not knowledgeable about AC grids but I vaguely understand that frequency plays the same role that voltage plays in DC circuits (and voltage in AC circuits has something to do with frequency and reactive power).

Just like batteries, power plant operators do have to be careful to synchronize their generators to the grid frequency and phase before connecting them, because connecting two AC generators in parallel forces their frequency and phase to be the same. Any would-be phase difference would cause a large current surge that would equalize the phase and could even make the generator explode. If you make sure the phase is equal (or almost equal) before connecting them, then it's fine. Frequency is the derivative of phase and the same rule applies as a generator with the same phase but different frequency will quickly get out of phase again. Like batteries, when the phase is locked, each  generator is supplying current to the best of its ability.